# Sencha-Touch 2.2.1 Simple drag works on Webkit browsers but not IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer, sencha-touch-2, draggable, internet-explorer-10, sencha-touch-2.2

I have a complex application which uses drag and drop in Sencha 2.2.1 - works brilliant on Webkit browsers, but now that Sencha Touch supports IE 10 I wanted to try it.

I could not get drag working, so I started a very simple test from scratch.

I built a new "hello world" app using sencha cmd generate and used the Main.js you see below.
I can drag the inner panel in webkit browsers no problem, but the inner panel does not even show up in IE 10. Tried for days, but can't quite figure out how this new Ext.util.Translatable deal works and how it is supposed to work in IE 10.

(Environment: Win 7 64 Bit; Sencha 2.2.1 Commercial SDK; Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342; build package like this 'sencha app build package' and run index.html from file folder w/ no webserver)

**view\Main.js:**

```
Ext.define('mytest.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
xtype: 'main',
requires: [
    'Ext.TitleBar',
    'Ext.Video',
    'Ext.util.Draggable'
],
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Welcome',
            iconCls: 'home',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scrollable: true,
            items: [{
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Welcome to Sencha Touch 2'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'hbox',
                html: 'mybutton',
                width: 300,
                height: 80,
                left: 5,
                top: 5,
                id: 'mydraggable',
                draggable: 'both',
                constraint: {
                    min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                    max: { x: 1000000, y: 1000000 }
                  },
                listeners: {
                    drag: {
                        element: 'element',
                        fn:  function(draggable, e){
                            console.log("left: ", this.getLeft(), "top: ",this.getTop(), "X: ",this.element.getX(), "Y: ",this.element.getY());
                            //this.setLeft(this.element.getX());
                            //this.setTop(this.element.getY());
                        }
                    },
                    tap: {
                        element: 'element',
                        fn: function(view, index, target, record, event){
                            alert("Tapped");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            title: 'Get Started',
            iconCls: 'action',

            items: [
                {
                    docked: 'top',
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    title: 'Getting Started'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'video',
                    url: 'http://av.vimeo.com/64284/137/87347327.mp4?token=1330978144_f9b698fea38cd408d52a2393240c896c',
                    posterUrl: 'http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/261/062/261062119_640.jpg'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
initialize: function (){

    this.callParent();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue while developing application with Sencha Touch framework. Drag functionality works good in -webkit browsers, but fails in IE10.

What I came up to is that for drag functionality sencha internal mechanisms are using 
-webkit-transform CSS property to translate components within the document.

As IE does not support these properties drag fails.

My suggestion to try to override default functionality and implement polyfill for any browser.

Sorry for not providing fix for this issue (currently developing). When I will have it working, I'll add it here.